# Laravel 4 Sending An Entire Form as a variable with jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel-4, jquery-forms-plugin

How do I use jQuery Form Plugin to send an ajax version of a form I am working on as a variable that can then be sent to a database? I am wanting to pull several inputs (such as order name and date) and put those in the database or organizational purposes but I want to be able to store the entire order form in the base as well so that the form can be called up and edited later if need be. jQuery Form Plugin seems ideal for doing this but it sends the form to a file destination, I am needing it to be sent to a variable so that I can then send it to a database. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send your form to Laravel, you just need jQuery do do it:

```
jQuery('#saveButton').click(function(evnt) {
    var href = $("#"+event.target.id).closest('form').attr('action');
    var form = $("#"+event.target.id).closest('form').attr('id');

    jQuery.post(href, jQuery("#"+form).serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        if (data.success == "true") {
            /// do what you need to do in case of success
        } else {
            /// do what you need to do in case of error
        }
    })

    return false;
});
```

What this does:

1) Set an event click on a button with id `saveButton`

2) get the form action

3) get the form id

4) serialize the whole form to Json

5) POST the form to the action url

6) My controller is supposed to return some `data`, with a `success` property, which I check and do whatever I need to do in the front end

In your Laravel controller you just need to:

```
Input::get('email');
Input::get('password');
```

You can even do:

```
Post::create(Input::all());
```

Note that `Input::all()` gives you an array of fields, so you can remove what you don't need. This is just an example to explain that there are lots of ways to store user fields in your table, this is just one, a very simple one:

```
$post = Post::find(Input::get('id'));

$post->title = Input::get('title');

$post->body = Input::get('body');

$input = Input::all();

unset($input['title']);

unset($input['body']);

$post->userFields = json_encode($input);

$post->save();
```

As you noted in your comment, you can make use Input::except() and loops to get what you need.

If you need to use those fields with `Form::model()`, you can stuff them back to your model:

```
$post = Post::find(1);

foreach(json_decode($post->userFields) as $key => $value)
{
    $post->attributes[$key] =  $value;
}
```

And then pass it:

```
Form::model($post...);
```

Comment: This looks great, my only concern is if it will, upon being called, upload not just the default form but any additional inputs the user has created. Right now I can get json_encode and decode to get the default part of the form to fill out but the additional fields are never created and filled. But this looks very promising, I will try it right now! Thanks!

Comment: The way it is, it will upload all inputs you have on your form. If your user managed to add some more inputs in your form, they will be uploaded as well. If you need to prevent that, you can serialize only the inputs you need to send to your app.

Comment: Oh okay. No the form is meant to be expandable when needed.

Comment: Looking through this I'm pretty sure I understand steps but once I get the form in its entirety sent to Laravel how do I select it to save all of it to my database?

Comment: And to clarify, I'm not trying to just save the inputs, as you pointed out Input::get('') works great for that. The problem I'm having is that when a user needs to expand a field (it might have 30 fields or a 140 or 80 or whatever depending on the user's needs) and I store it, all the info is there but when I pull it up in case they need to edit it the information is still all there but only the default fields are created and filled. Everything beyond the default is not created nor filled, despite the information still existing in the database.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more info if you need the answer to be specific. But I edited to give you some options. You'll have your data available via Input::all(), which may be used to send to directly to your database.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, in my OrderController that is used for this form I had previously used `$order_serialized  = json_encode(Input::except('_token', 'submit'));` to input the default form and any additional fields the user had added with a "Add" button. This saves all of the data but when I try to use form model binding with `{{ Form::model($order, .... ` only the default section of the form shows up. Now the data for the entire form has been stored, as I can see it when I use dd($order->order_serialized) but only the default fields are being created and filled in and the additional info is not

Comment: So my thinking was to try to ajax the ENTIRE form instead of just the data inputs to try to get around this seems much more elegant if I can figure out how to select the entire form (default and user created fields) and plug it into a database in a way that will allow for the entire form to show.

Comment: You may need to create separate table, to hold those fields and create a relation between your user and your order.

Comment: But you also can stuff those fields back to your Orders model, any attributes you add to your orders will be used by `Form::model()`